# Get parent to child relation with mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have one collection called "location". in this collection all child and parent collection are stores. now I want to create a query who returns me parent to child comma separated string.

**Collection**

```
businessId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'admin' },
parentId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'location' },
name: { type: String },
image: { type: String },
imageManipulation: { type: String },
locationColor: [{ range: { type: String }, color: { type: String } }],
area: {},
settings: {},
status: { type: String, enum: [0, 1], default: 1 },
isChild: { type: String, enum: [0, 1] },
parentPosition: { type: String }
```

In the above collection, you can see `parentId` field. if the location is a child then it have `parentId`. if the location is a parent then parentId will null. parent location can N level child location.

**Collection Data**

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce4f84547e90a0b9c3c4763"),
    "name": "Test",
    "settings": {
        "zoom": "3",
        "positionX": "69",
        "positionY": "69",
        "width": "500",
        "height": "334"
    },
    "parentId": null,
    "image": "1558509637101.jpg",
    "status": "0",
    "businessId": ObjectId("5cbd61dc3b56b902284ea388"),
    "locationColor": [],
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2019-05-22T12:59:26.013Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2019-05-22T07:20:37.112Z"),
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce50caf09359e1b8ccf5c79"),
    "name": "Test sub 1",
    "settings": {
        "zoom": "3",
        "positionX": "48",
        "positionY": "3",
        "width": "500",
        "height": "334"
    },
    "area": "",
    "parentId": ObjectId("5ce4f84547e90a0b9c3c4763"),
    "image": "1558514863396.jpg",
    "status": "0",
    "businessId": ObjectId("5cbd61dc3b56b902284ea388"),
    "locationColor": [],
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2019-05-22T12:59:21.883Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2019-05-22T08:47:43.421Z"),
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce53977e46da33e6cfdd9d1"),
    "name": "Test Sub 2",
    "settings": {
        "zoom": "5",
        "positionX": "0",
        "positionY": "0",
        "width": "500",
        "height": "334"
    },
    "area": "",
    "parentId": ObjectId("5ce50caf09359e1b8ccf5c79"),
    "image": "1558526327126.jpg",
    "businessId": ObjectId("5cbd61dc3b56b902284ea388"),
    "locationColor": [],
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2019-05-22T11:58:47.147Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2019-05-22T11:58:47.147Z"),
    "__v": 0
}]
```

> Expected Result

Test, Test sub 1, Test Sub 2

> Expected result in JSON

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce4f84547e90a0b9c3c4763"),
    "name": "Test",
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce50caf09359e1b8ccf5c79"),
    "name": "Test, Test sub 1",
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce53977e46da33e6cfdd9d1"),
    "name": "Test, Test sub 1, Test Sub 2",
}]
```

Comment: Could you show result in JSON format which can be produced from the above sample data.

Comment: what mongo version are you on?

Comment: @tomslabbaert I am using 3.4 mongo version

Comment: and you want the return value to already be string and not use code at all? would an array suffice?

Comment: @Fanpark I edit the question and add as Expected result in JSON. please check

Comment: @tomslabbaert sorry It's my mistake to expected result in a string. I edit the question add **Expected result in JSON** please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need [**`$graphLookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) for recursive loop over the same collection.

```
db.location.aggregate([
  { "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "location",
    "startWith": "$parentId",
    "connectFromField": "parentId",
    "connectToField": "_id",
    "as": "parent"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": {
      "$concat": [
        "$name",
        { "$reduce": {
          "input": "$parent",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": { "$concat": [",", "$$this.name", "$$value"] }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Which will output

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce4f84547e90a0b9c3c4763"),
    "name": "Test"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce50caf09359e1b8ccf5c79"),
    "name": "Test sub 1,Test"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ce53977e46da33e6cfdd9d1"),
    "name": "Test Sub 2,Test sub 1,Test"
  }
]
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t12satGYVFF)